# How to disconnect SignalR Hub Client after Jwt token expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, jwt

I have been playing ChatHub example of Microsoft to get some knowledge about newly released net-core signalR. I implemented the Jwt authentication and added Authorize to my Hub. And I configured my Jwt authentication to validate expiration. But if the client connects to the hub successfully while the token is valid. It stays connected even after token expires. The client can't post-get any request to same server's other end-points but gets all push notifications. You can see my playground [here](https://github.com/ilkerkaran/MySignalRPlayGround)

**My question is**: is there any workaround to disconnect client after Jwt token expires?

Answer (score 2):

You have to track connections by yourself.

Here is example of connection storage that can be used in code you have provided

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace SignalRServer.API.Hubs
{
  public class HubConnectionsStorage
  {
    private readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> _connectionsByJwtToken;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _jwtTokenByConnection;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> _connectionsByGroup;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> _groupsByConnection;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

    public HubConnectionsStorage()
    {
      _connectionsByJwtToken = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
      _jwtTokenByConnection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      _connectionsByGroup = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
      _groupsByConnection = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
      _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }

    public void AddConnection(string connectionId, string jwtToken)
    {
      _lock.EnterWriteLock();

      try
      {
        _jwtTokenByConnection[connectionId] = jwtToken;

        if (!_connectionsByJwtToken.TryGetValue(jwtToken, out var connections))
          _connectionsByJwtToken[jwtToken] = connections = new HashSet<string>();

        connections.Add(connectionId);
      }
      finally
      {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
      }
    }

    public void AddConnectionToGroup(string connectionId, string group)
    {
      _lock.EnterWriteLock();

      try
      {
        if(!_connectionsByGroup.TryGetValue(group, out var connections))
          _connectionsByGroup[group] = connections = new HashSet<string>();

        connections.Add(connectionId);

        if (!_groupsByConnection.TryGetValue(connectionId, out var groups))
          _groupsByConnection[connectionId] = groups = new HashSet<string>();

        groups.Add(group);

      }
      finally
      {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
      }
    }

    public void RemoveConnectionFromGroup(string connectionId, string group)
    {
      _lock.EnterWriteLock();

      try
      {
        if (!_connectionsByGroup.TryGetValue(group, out var connections))
          return;

        if(!connections.Remove(connectionId))
          return;

        if (connections.Count == 0)
          _connectionsByGroup.Remove(group);

        var groups = _groupsByConnection[connectionId];

        groups.Remove(group);

        if (groups.Count == 0)
          _groupsByConnection.Remove(connectionId);
      }
      finally
      {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
      }
    }

    public void RemoveConnection(string connectionId)
    {
      _lock.EnterWriteLock();

      try
      {
        if(!_jwtTokenByConnection.TryGetValue(connectionId, out var jwtToken))
          return;

        _jwtTokenByConnection.Remove(connectionId);

        var jwtConnections = _connectionsByJwtToken[jwtToken];

        jwtConnections.Remove(connectionId);

        if (jwtConnections.Count == 0)
          _connectionsByJwtToken.Remove(jwtToken);

        if(!_groupsByConnection.TryGetValue(connectionId, out var groups))
          return;

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
          var connections = _connectionsByGroup[group];
          connections.Remove(connectionId);

          if (connections.Count == 0)
            _connectionsByGroup.Remove(group);
        }

        _groupsByConnection.Remove(connectionId);
      }
      finally
      {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
      }
    }

    public List<string> GetGroupConnections(string group)
    {
      _lock.EnterReadLock();

      try
      {
        if (_connectionsByGroup.TryGetValue(group, out var connections))
          return connections.ToList();

        return new List<string>();
      }
      finally 
      {
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
      }
    }

    public void RemoveExpiredConnections(Func<string, bool> validateJwtToken)
    {
      _lock.EnterWriteLock();

      try
      {
        foreach (var jwtToken in _connectionsByJwtToken.Keys.ToList())
        {
          var isValid = validateJwtToken(jwtToken);

          if (isValid) 
            continue;

          var invalidConnections = _connectionsByJwtToken[jwtToken];

          foreach (var invalidConnection in invalidConnections)
          {
            if (_groupsByConnection.TryGetValue(invalidConnection, out var connectionGroups))
            {
              foreach (var group in connectionGroups)
              {
                var groupConnections = _connectionsByGroup[@group];
                groupConnections.Remove(invalidConnection);

                if (groupConnections.Count == 0)
                  _connectionsByGroup.Remove(@group);
              }

              _groupsByConnection.Remove(invalidConnection);
            }

            _jwtTokenByConnection.Remove(invalidConnection);
          }

          _connectionsByJwtToken.Remove(jwtToken);
        }
      }
      finally 
      {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can pass it as singleton to your hub

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignalRServer.API.Services;

namespace SignalRServer.API.Hubs
{
[Authorize]
public class NewsHub : Hub
{
private readonly NewsService newsService;
private readonly HubConnectionsStorage connectionsStorage;

public NewsHub(NewsService newsService, HubConnectionsStorage connectionsStorage)
{
  this.newsService = newsService;
  this.connectionsStorage = connectionsStorage;
}

public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
  var jwtToken = GetCurrentConnectionJwtToken();
  connectionsStorage.AddConnection(Context.ConnectionId, jwtToken);
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
  connectionsStorage.RemoveConnection(Context.ConnectionId);
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public async Task Send((string groupName, string generatedNews) news)
{
  if (!newsService.CheckTopic(news.groupName))
    throw new Exception("cannot send a news item to a group which does not exist.");

  connectionsStorage.RemoveExpiredConnections(ValidateJwtToken);

  var groupConnections = connectionsStorage.GetGroupConnections(news.groupName);
  await Clients.Clients(groupConnections).SendAsync("NewsFeed", news.generatedNews);
}

public async Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
  if (!newsService.CheckTopic(groupName))
    throw new Exception("cannot join a group which does not exist.");

  connectionsStorage.AddConnectionToGroup(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

  var groupConnections = connectionsStorage.GetGroupConnections(groupName);

  await Clients.Clients(groupConnections).SendAsync("JoinGroup", groupName);

  var history = newsService.GetTopicNews(groupName);
  await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("History", history);
}

public async Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
{
  if (!newsService.CheckTopic(groupName))
    throw new Exception("cannot leave a group which does not exist.");

  var groupConnections = connectionsStorage.GetGroupConnections(groupName);

  await Clients.Clients(groupConnections).SendAsync("LeaveGroup", groupName);
  connectionsStorage.RemoveConnectionFromGroup(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}

private string GetCurrentConnectionJwtToken() => "fake jwt token "+Random.Next(4);
private bool ValidateJwtToken(string jwtToken) => Random.NextDouble() >= 0.5;

private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
}
}
```

This is just an example to get the idea. Modify it to suite your needs.
I hope it will help )

Comment: I think if I can modify the locking logic to lock only related group records(this will reduce lock's performance issue) I can use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to have a mapping of connections and tokens. Iterate through the tokens and if one is expired disconnect the according client.

Comment: Can you elaborate your suggestion with an example? I would like to try the approach.